# perform button click in webView Android studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-webview, element

I need help. I Want to click on a button on my webView in Android studio. The button is actually search button with button id="search-icon-legacy" in HTML code. I wrote this code but it did nothing but open youtube in my android browser, not performing click on search button. can any one pls help me ? here is my code in MainActivity.java:

````
```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings faller = view.getSettings();
        faller.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('search-icon-legacy').click();})();");
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

To perform some click envent in webview, if you can edit the web code or know the function name called when the button is clicked, you can do like that:

This is the **JavaScript called on the web**:

```js
    function androidFinish() {
            Android.finish();
        }
```

**Create your WebInterface**, this class will be setup on your webView to say what you want to do when function JavaScript is called.

```kotlin
    class WebAppInterface(private val context: Context) {
    
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun finish() {
            (context as Activity).finish()
        }
    
    }
```

Here, the function named finish will, as is named, finish the activity passed as context.

Then in your activity that you implement the webView:

1. Make sure you enable JS on your webView as :

```kotlin
webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

2. Config your webView to your webInterface :

```kotlin
webview.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "Android")
```

Here, the `"Android"` reference the root **call function**, as you can see on the **JS code**. Then the `".finish()"` can be referenced in the function name called on your **WebInterface**.

*source on android documentation :* https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript